# Finding out the first time android device was turned on

Tags: android, android-debug

Is there a way to figure out the first time an android device was turned on through an app?

Possible ideas that I have is accessing log files, or analysing last date of modified on certain files on the device. I can also access the first call/sms, but I imagine the user can easily wipe that data. However, I wasn't able to find which files are accessible by an android app.

Comment: Did you find out how to do it.?

Comment: No, did you @PranavKarnik?

Comment: No :( @AryanGoharzad